# Juniper Qualified Next Hop for Ipsec Tunnels

Tags: juniper, ipsec

I've got one VPN with 2 links going from my SRX to AWS. Both tunnels are bound to an st0. interface with qualified-next-hop:

```
route 192.168.0.0/23 { 
qualified-next-hop 169.251.233.29 { 
interface st0.4; 
} 
qualified-next-hop 169.254.233.25 { 
interface st0.5; 
}
```

My problem is that even when a tunnel associated with an interface is down the interface is showing as up and traffic is attempting to route through it.

**How can I prevent traffic from routing over a "down" IPSec interface?**

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the SRX, a down tunnel should also take down your st0.x interface as well, in which case your configuration should work fine.

A couple of reasons for this not working: I have seen a few versions of Junos that broke this (early 12.1X44 releases), so a code upgrade may fix this.  I'm using 12.1X46D55 on an SRX240 and it correctly drops the st0.x interface when the tunnel is down.

Also, ensure that you have DPD (dead-peer detection) enabled, so that the box doesn't wait for a re-key interval to know that the far side is down.  AWS supports this by default, so you should be able to fail over in ~30 seconds.